# Which string comparer is used with switch statements?

Tags: c#, string, switch-statement, string-comparison, cultureinfo

How are strings compared when doing `switch` statements? Does the current culture of the thread / computer affect `switch` evaluation? I got in the habit of always specifying a comparer when comparing strings, so it would be great to have this confirmed.

I suspect it's `StringComparer.Ordinal`, but I cannot find any documentation on this.

Comment: See source : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Switch.cs,3e925a7e08f32940

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the current culture of the thread / computer affect switch
>   evaluation?

No, it does not.

`switch`, uses [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_Object_) under the covers. Thus it is ordinal:

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive) comparison.

How do we know `switch` uses `Equals`? Well [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement) state:

> The constant expression is evaluated as follows:
>
> - If expr and constant are integral types, the C# equality operator
>     determines whether the expression returns true (that is, whether expr
>     == constant).
> - Otherwise, the value of the expression is determined by a call to the
>     static Object.Equals(expr, constant) method.

The latter bullet point is what applies here.

Comment: So, it is not literally using `StringComparer.Ordinal` but it is doing that same comparison.

Comment: _Effectively_ yes @DavidS. Although https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/stringcomparer.cs,350 shows that `StringComparer.Ordinal` uses `String.Equals` (rather than the other way around).